# jQuery Select converts to Select2 with no dropdown options

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

My application pulls dropdown list options using an API and dynamically creates the dropdowns inline in the table when the user clicks an edit button. Everything was working as expected using jQuery's basic "Select" functionality. Aaaaand then I saw Select2 with all of its shininess and built in search boxes. Since my lists will become quite long in production, that's functionality I really should have. I've seen many snippets where people simply call .select2() on the select item and have it working out of the box. I get the box, but it's not working :) The Select2 box appears and has the correct dropdown item selected, but when I click on the box there are no dropdown options.

I've duplicated the basic functionality and structure of my application, including simulated API data responses. Is there a way to make the existing select function work or do I need to build it from the ground up using Select2? Further, based on my data structure, is that even possible?

Thanks for taking a look!

JS Fiddle includes the same code but is included for your editing convenience:
https://jsfiddle.net/tekowalski/amrhjo6y/9/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#edit_btn').click(function () {
    let clickedRow = $($(this).closest('td')).closest('tr');
    $(clickedRow).find('td').each(function () {
      if ($(this).hasClass('edit_account')) {
        fnCreateDropdown($(this), option_data);
      }
    });
  });

  function fnCreateDropdown(obj, options) {
    let html = '<select type="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">';
    let account_type = '';
    let grouped = false;

    for (var idx in options) {
      let my_act_type = options[idx]['account_type_name']; // Set Account Type
      if(my_act_type !== account_type) {
        if(grouped === true) { // Close out option group if one has been made
          html += '</optgroup>'
        }
        
        html += '<optgroup label="' + my_act_type + '">'
        grouped = true;
        
        account_type = my_act_type; // Set account_type for next loop

      }
      if (options[idx]['id'] === 2) {
        selected = ' selected ';
      } else {
        selected = '';
      }
      html += '<option ' + selected + 'id="' + options[idx]['id'] + '">' + options[idx]['name'] + '</option>';
    }

    html += '</optgroup></select>';
    obj.html($(html));
    $(obj).select2(); // Comment out this line for a functional select with dropdown options
  }

  option_data = [
    {account_type_id: 1, account_type_name: 'Asset', id: 1, name: 'Asset Account'},
    {account_type_id: 2, account_type_name: 'Expense', id: 2, name: 'Expense Account'}
    ]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Account Name</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="edit_account">
      Expense Account
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id='edit_btn'>Edit</button>
      </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it because you need a special data format to populate the select2: https://select2.org/data-sources/formats

Comment: Your `obj` is not a `<select>` - change to `obj.find("select").select2();` and it works fine.

Comment: @freedomn-m - woah, so simple. My actual application still crashes with a "toString" error but that succinctly answers my question here. Post as an answer and I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.select2()` must be applied to a `<select>` element.

In this case, `obj.select2()` does not apply to a `<select>` as it's the container that the dynamically generated `select` is inserted into.

Change

```
$(obj).select2();
```

to

```
obj.find("select").select2()
```

to apply to the `select` inside the container.

Side note: `obj` is already a jquery object, so there's no need to wrap it again, but it does not harm other than a tiny overhead.

Updated snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#edit_btn').click(function () {
    let clickedRow = $($(this).closest('td')).closest('tr');
    $(clickedRow).find('td').each(function () {
      if ($(this).hasClass('edit_account')) {
        fnCreateDropdown($(this), option_data);
      }
    });
  });

  function fnCreateDropdown(obj, options) {
    let html = '<select type="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">';
    let account_type = '';
    let grouped = false;

    for (var idx in options) {
      let my_act_type = options[idx]['account_type_name']; // Set Account Type
      if(my_act_type !== account_type) {
        if(grouped === true) { // Close out option group if one has been made
          html += '</optgroup>'
        }
        
        html += '<optgroup label="' + my_act_type + '">'
        grouped = true;
        
        account_type = my_act_type; // Set account_type for next loop

      }
      if (options[idx]['id'] === 2) {
        selected = ' selected ';
      } else {
        selected = '';
      }
      html += '<option ' + selected + 'id="' + options[idx]['id'] + '">' + options[idx]['name'] + '</option>';
    }

    html += '</optgroup></select>';
    obj.html($(html));
    obj.find("select").select2(); 
  }

  option_data = [
    {account_type_id: 1, account_type_name: 'Asset', id: 1, name: 'Asset Account'},
    {account_type_id: 2, account_type_name: 'Expense', id: 2, name: 'Expense Account'}
    ]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Account Name</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="edit_account">
      Expense Account
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id='edit_btn'>Edit</button>
      </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```